# Function is not defined within a cog discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to clean up my code by putting it into cogs. For some reason whenever I try and call a function I get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'get_bank_data' is not defined
```

even thought it is. Here is my code(I cut out the other commands to make it easier to read).

```py
class RpgCog(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
  async def open_account(self, user):

     users = await get_bank_data()

     if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
     else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["hp"] = 20
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 100
        users[str(user.id)]["leather_armour"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]['stone_sword'] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]['health_potion'] = 5
        users[str(user.id)]['maxhp'] = 20
        users[str(user.id)]['kingdom'] = 1
        users[str(user.id)]['max_damage'] = 5
        users[str(user.id)]['min_damage'] = 1
        users[str(user.id)]['xp'] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]['agility'] = 20
        users[str(user.id)]['hermes_boots'] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]['leather_armour_equipped'] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]['stone_sword_equipped'] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]['no_sword'] = 1
        users[str(user.id)]['no_armour'] = 1
        users[str(user.id)]['fishing_rod'] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]['fishing_luck'] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]['fishing_rod_equipped'] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]['no_rod'] = 1

         with open('mainbank.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

        return True

    async def get_bank_data(self, client):
       with open('mainbank.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

   @commands.command(name='bal')
   async def print_bal(self, ctx):
     user = ctx.author
     await RpgCog.open_account(self, user)
     users = await RpgCog.get_bank_data(self)
      
     bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]['bank']

     await ctx.channel.send(bank_amt)


def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(RpgCog(client))
```

Here is the code I'm using to call the cog in my main.py

```py
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
  if filename.endswith('.py'):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation... It's not even possible to read the code, it's a mess

Comment: Ok will do that now

Comment: Also I believe you're getting the error cause of the incorrect indentation

Comment: Indentation is fixed @ŁukaszKwieciński

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In classes to access methods and properties you need to use `self`

So use `await self.get_bank_data()`

There is no need of `client` argument in `get_bank_data` function, remove that

Comment: I just tried it and i still got the same error, I'm not sure why. First it said missing argument 'users' on open_account so I added it then I got the error that get_bank_data isn't found

Comment: Wait my bad, the open_account function calls get_bank_data in it and I didn't change it to self.get_bank_data()

Comment: glad it works! comment if you need something else